# Smarty foreach from 0 to a number

Tags: arrays, loops, foreach, smarty

I am trying to create a pagination on a template. I need a helping hand.
I have a total page count: $numberOfPage.
I would like to loop over it to display my pages.
However, it is a number and not an array.
I don't know how to make it loop between "1" and my total page count to create my navigation.

Here is the piece of code I created.
Thanks for any help.

```
                    <ol class="">
                    {foreach $numberOfPage as $page }
                        {dump($numberOfPage)}
                        {if !$page@first}
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="">
                                    <span class="icon-chevron-left"></span>
                                    Préc.
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="">{$page-1}</a>
                            </li>
                        {/if}
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="">{$page}</a>
                        </li>
                        {if !$page@last}
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="">{$page+1}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="">
                                    Suiv.
                                    <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {/if}
                    {/foreach}
                </ol>
```

Comment: consider the using the normal for loop  {for($page=0; $page<$numberOfPage; $page++ }, or initialize the $page to whatever the first pages is for the current pagination or create an array of size  $numberOfPage and populated with 1 to $numberOfPage allowing use the foreach  stmt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty provides a [`for`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl)  function.